# Shiny and Javascript - Uncaught ReferenceError: TRUE is not defined

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a shinyapp which has a basic login screen.

When the app loads, the "Logged" variable is FALSE. When the user successfully logs in within the session, the R login code is as follows:

```
X$Logged <- TRUE
```

At this point, in the javascript console I get warnings saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: TRUE is not defined".

I click on the link to go to the code, and the javascript code is:

```
(function() {
with (this) {return (X$Logged=TRUE);}
})
```

I am a beginner. I am assuming that firstly, this is the javascript render of my R code above, and secondly that it doesn't like it because javascript expects a lower case boolean "true".

How can I get around this?  Equally, R doesn't like lower case boolean.

Comment: try `true` at the place of `TRUE`. means in lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get around this? Equally, R doesn't like lower case boolean.

Define one in the other, e.g. as you're going to *JavaScript*, before your code (in the *JavaScript*)

```js
var TRUE = true, FALSE = false;
```

Then

```js
(function() {
    with (this) {return (X$Logged=TRUE);} // should now work
})
```

---

Alternatively, you could use bool-like things, i.e. `1` and `0` instead.

Finally, how are you doing the R to JS transformation? This well may be a bug in the framework you've used

Comment: I am running a shiny app.  So, all of my code is in R.  When I run the app, shiny converts my R code into JS (I assume, at some point) and displays in the browser.  Therefore the warnings and errors are output as errors in JS functions, however I haven't written any JS, and don't have control over the conversion from R to JS.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's and Mritunjay's answer helped me to get this fixed.

The misunderstanding was in a conditionalPanel() within my ui.R file.  I had:

```
conditionalPanel(
condition="X$Logged=TRUE"
...
)
```

I spotted the single "=" instead of "==" and realised the condition within the inverted commas is JS, and not R.  I therefore changed my ui.R to this:

```
conditionalPanel(
condition="X$Logged=true"
...
)
```

However, I kept upper case "TRUE" in all of my server.R logic, like this:

```
X$Logged <- TRUE
```

...and it now works.